# How to prove the Derivative-Integral Relationship on a Closed Ball Domain?

Tags: calculus

Consider a closed region $D(x, y):=\left\{(\xi, \eta) \mid(\xi-x)^2+(\eta-y)^2 \leqslant r^2\right\}$, and let $f \in C\left(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}\right)$. Define
$$
F(x, y)=\int_{D(x, y)} f(\xi, \eta) \mathrm{d} S .
$$

How can we prove that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x, y)=\int_{\partial D(x, y)^{+}} f(\xi, \eta) \mathrm{d} \eta \\
& \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(x, y)=-\int_{\partial D(x, y)^{+}} f(\xi, \eta) \mathrm{d} \xi
\end{aligned}
$$

More generally, for a ball $B(\boldsymbol{y} ; r) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, where $\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and a continuous function $f$, how can we calculate " $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d} F}{\mathrm{~d} \boldsymbol{y}^{\mathrm{T}}}(\boldsymbol{y}), \boldsymbol{y}:=\left(y_1, \cdots, y_n\right)^{\mathrm{T}}$ "?